# Why is this application’s (Mou) window always on in front of all other windows in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, finder

I am using [Mou](http://25.io/mou/) to edit Mardown documents in Mac OS X 10.9.5 and recently it’s oddly been pushing its windows to the front of all applications I have open. I don’t recall this behavior happening in the past and it’s quite frustrating to say the least.

I have attempted to clear the Mou application cache in `~/Library/Caches/com.mouapp.Mou/` as well as trash the preferences plist in `~/Library/Preferences/com.mouapp.Mou.plist` still no change so I don’t believe this is connected to the application. So could this be a “Finder” feature I was not aware of that I might have accidentally triggered after hitting a “magical”—and annoying—key combo? Screenshot below.

Note how the “Terminal” app is the selected app in focus, but note how the new document window in Mou is in front of “Terminal” window. Also note that the Mou document has a lighter colored “I should be in the background…” title bar despite it clearly being in front of the “Terminal” window.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Yes, there is a key combo which triggers it, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> +
  <kbd>COMMAND</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. Screenshot Below:

[image]

- For me it works perfectly fine on 10.10.1 Yosemite. Screenshot Below:

[image]

- This feature was added in version 0.8.2. [Release Notes](http://25.io/mou/releasenotes/) Below:

> Floating Window ( View > Toggle Floating <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> ), make Window always floating on top of other apps.